# ServerSpec failing on Windows 7 when running tests

Tags: ruby, windows, serverspec

I recently tried to create a ServerSpec job, using Ruby 2.1.6 for Windows. However, using the code at [the following GitHub repo](https://github.com/predatorian3/serverspec_windows), I get the following errors.

```
C:\Users\PD028300\Desktop\serverspec_test\windows_spec
λ rake spec
C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.2.2/lib';'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib' 'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/localhost/*_spec.rb'
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
  should be file (FAILED - 1)
  content (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" should be file
     On host `localhost'
     Failure/Error: it { should be_file }
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
       uname -s
       MINGW32_NT-6.1

     # ./spec/localhost/hosts_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" content
     On host `localhost'
     Failure/Error: it(:content) { should match /localhost/ }
       expected File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" to match /localhost/
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -/localhost/
       +File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"


     # ./spec/localhost/hosts_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.82 seconds (files took 0.6677 seconds to load)
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/localhost/hosts_spec.rb:4 # File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" should be file
rspec ./spec/localhost/hosts_spec.rb:5 # File "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts" content

C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-support-3.2.2/lib';'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib' 'C:/Ruby/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec' --pattern 'spec/localhost/*_spec.rb' failed
```

Is this something to do with the file I'm trying to describe, being that its the hosts file on a Windows machine?

Comment: have you set the os in your spec file? (set :os, :family => 'windows') without the parenthesis

Comment: Ah, I had to set the :os :family in the spec_helper.rb file, which I had not done. Once I did that, it worked. I'll get my answer put up in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back and recreating the ServerSpec file, it still didn't work. After a re-reading the tutorial, http://serverspec.org/tutorial.html and https://github.com/serverspec/serverspec/blob/master/WINDOWS_SUPPORT.md , I added the OS family setting in the spec_helper.rb and it started working.

The final result of the spec_helper.rb is:

```
require 'serverspec'

set :backend, :cmd
set :os, :family => 'windows'
```

Now the spec's I made worked! Just make sure to require the spec_helper